# Can't we rewrite migration table and reset the migration file instead of using column modifiers?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a bit confused with this. Can't we just rewrite the migration table and reset the migration instead of using modifying column modifiers?
For eg. `$table->string('name', 50)->change();` 
can't we just change the size to 25 (say) and refresh the migration instead of using change()? What difference does it make?

Comment: Yes you can. But, refreshing the migration couldn't be always possible. Note that, refreshing the migration deletes all your data. So, if your database contains information, then you might not want to refresh the migration. Do you @Azima?

Comment: @vijayrana.. no I don't.. :) thanks for the help

Comment: you are welcome @Azima :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just do this:

`php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

This will drop the tables, recreate them and populate them using your seeders.